# How to add prebuild app in data in AOSP source code

Tags: build, android-source

regarding to this post, I have set
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_DATA)

After building the App is located in data, but it is not shown/available after booting. it is not found in App drawer nor in Setting/apps

Is there something I have done wrong?

Comment: Do you flash userdata img?

Comment: no, I'm building / flashing GSI (system.img)

Comment: I have just tried on a rom build where userdata is also flashed. The apk is in data as I can see in build sources, but after rom flashing the app is not available